# How to add diacritics to my phonetic transcription?

Tags: discussion, support

When I need phonetic symbols, I just copy them off of Wikipedia. I don't know how to add diacritics with this method though. Take ◌̥ for example. When I try to delete the dotted circle, and replace it with a letter, the diacritic is always deleted first. What do I do?

Comment: Microsoft Word International Keyboard...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you copy the HTML code for the combining character (`&#805;`), you can put it after the character you want to modify. It's easy as
Ḁ
B̥
C̥!

That is,

```
A&#805;
B&#805;
C&#805;
```

I found the HTML code on [unicode-table](https://unicode-table.com/en/0325/), but you can really just google up a site.

Comment: And does this work for multiple diacritics on the same symbol?

Comment: Never mind, I checked it and it's possible to just string them along :)

Comment: Yes, you can put an HTML code for another diacritic after the first (and so on) and they combine with the one character you want to modify.

Answer (score 5):

By far and away the easiest method is to go to [IPA.typeit.org](https://ipa.typeit.org). Use their full keyboard, type whatever you want with whatever diacritics, and then cut and paste into your post.